# DOM jQuery finding next and previous element to current

Tags: jquery, dom

How to find next and previous "A" element from "#current" using jQuery.
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
        <a id='current'></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i've tried to create a code with something like this:

```
var curr = $('#current');
var prev = curr.parent().prev('a');
var next = curr.parent().next('a');
```

But it didn't work. I think it's a very easy questions, but i'm stuck right now. Any ideas?

**UPD:** It should travel to next "LI" element to find "A" if it's the last "A" element in current "LI".

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to use parent to get prev and next

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Skg46/1/)**

```
var curr = $('#current');
var prev = curr.prev('a');
var next = curr.next('a');
```

To make this cross row you need to check if you have current element first or last of row. If current element is first then last would be last element for previous row and similarly if current element is last of row then next will be first of next row.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Skg46/5/)**

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('ul > li > a').css('background-color', 'white');
    var curr = $(this);
    curr.css('background-color', 'green');;
    var prev = curr.prev('a')
    if(prev.length == 0 )
    {
        lastaOfPrevLi = curr.parent().prev();
        if( lastaOfPrevLi.length != 0)
            lastaOfPrevLi.find('a:last').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    else
        prev.css('background-color', 'red');
    var next = curr.next('a');
    if(next.length == 0 )
    {
        lastaOfNextLi = curr.parent().next();
        if( lastaOfNextLi.length != 0)
            lastaOfNextLi.find('a:first').css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
    else
            next.css('background-color', 'orange');
});
```

Comment: In the live demo posted above if I click 6, 7 does not turn green.

Comment: I think you are talking about the missing previous for first and missing next of last item in the row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look beyond the `LI` of `#current` will need a different approach since `nex()` and `prev()` only look for imediate siblings

```
var curr = $('#current');
/* check if there is previous sibling, otherwise get last "a" in previous "LI"*/
var prev = curr.prev().length ? curr.prev() : curr.parent().prev().find('a:last');
var next = curr.next().length ? curr.next() : curr.parent().prev().find('a:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery docs and my own quick experiment, it does not look like  `next` or `previous` will get elements outside the parent. Those methods are supposed to get the immediate sibling of the current element regardless of type, unless a selector is used. Elements under a different parent wouldn't be counted as siblings, they're more like cousins.

What you could do to accomplish your goal would look more like the following

```
var current = $("#current");
var prev = current.prev();
var next = current.next().length > 0 ? current.next() : current.parent().next().first()
```

You could do the same with `prev` using `prev().last()` instead of `next().first()` should `current` be the first child of its parent element.

You can try it out in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arosen/ucR2f/).